# Is there a way to create,edit, or list rubrics?

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

Is there a way to create,edit, or list rubrics?

I see in the documentation I can create coursework, but one of the key pieces of coursework is the rubric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the option of editing, creating and/or listing rubrics through the API is **not possible**.

You can do all of the things mentioned above by using the **Beta version of the Google Classroom** by using the UI available.

For more information on that matter, you can check the following links.

- [Rubrics Beta Participation Application](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSew_1wZ81aN_xy2jpZHEKr5duoGx8w6yJ738ZkpZh3S5WSHaA/viewform);
- [Sign up for Classroom beta programs](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9191110);
- [Grade with a rubric](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9335428?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0).

Answer (score 0):

Rubrics have not been added to the CourseWork API however there is an issue in the Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130443624).